# Laravel4 task to cron

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm trying to create a cron using a task I made. The problem is I have no clue how to build the cron. My task name is meeting:close, and it's in my commands folder.

Can anyone help me to build the url to call this task every hour? I guess it will start with 0 * * * *

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you know how to set up a cronjob in general?

Comment: no, and it my biggest issue to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a cronjob, you have to edit a file. It is pretty easy, run `crontab -e` to edit the cron file for the current user.

Now just add a line to the file that opens:

```
0 * * * * php /full/path/to/your/application/artisan meeting:close
```

*Maybe you also have to specify the absolute path to your `php` executable*

Now save the file and you're all set.

By the way, if you didn't know, you can run your commands with `php artisan command:name` from the terminal (that's also what the cronjob is going to do...)